# Can you see a fractal in primes in base binary?

Tags: prime-numbers, fractals

I'm currently writing a computer program that computes prime numbers, and then, it give me on binary base.  The structure is obviously $1XX\dotso XX1$. The first $1$ and the last $1$, are common, because all primes are odd except $2$.

If the binary expansions of the primes between $2^N$ and $2^{N+1}$ are written in an array, the pattern of $1$s and $0$s appears to have a fractal structure.  For example, these are prime numbers from $256$ to $512$:

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 - 257
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1
1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1
1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 - 509
```

If we represent the transpose of this matrix as a raster array with each $1$ as a black square and each $0$ as a white square, we generate the following image:

[image]

Can we explain the apparent fractal structure in this image?

Comment: What do you mean by "*I can see a fractal*"? Where? What is a "fractal"?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal. Replace 0 with spaces in the example before.

Comment: That still doesn't make a fractal... Can you please give a full example of that fractal?

Comment: This example is only for the primes between 256 and 512. The idea of the fractal, is when you collect primes between $2^n$ and $2^{n-1}$ and let n the limit to infinite. I'll try to paint it with more time.What is a fractal for you?

Comment: No. When you collect primes between $2^n$ and $2^{n-1}$, you will end up with a collection of primes between $2^n$ and $2^{n-1}$. I still don't see how you get to a "fractal" from there.

Comment: ... 1. Collect the primes between. 2. Convert all to binary base. 3. Change the 0 by blank spaces. 4. Put all in a column...

Comment: @RobertoCarlosJoaquinCastro Does the image that I added look about like you expect? If so, I have a reasonable response which I suppose I could add, if the question were not closed.

Comment: Yes @Mark McClure, its like that image. I imagine it transposed. But yes, this is the figure.

Answer (score 6):

I *think* that the fractal like structure is really arising from the simple repetitive patterns that we see when looking at consecutive integers in base 2. Note, for example, the similarity of the red blocks in the base 2 expansions of the numbers 1 through 7 below:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & \color{red}0 & \color{red}1 \\
 0 & \color{red}1 & \color{red}0 \\
 0 & \color{red}1 & \color{red}1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & \color{red}0 & \color{red}1 \\
 1 & \color{red}1 & \color{red}0 \\
 1 & \color{red}1 & \color{red}1 \\
\end{array}
$$

If write the numbers $2^7=128$ through $2^8=155$ in base two and color and rasterize (essentially representing a zero as a white block and a one as a black block), then we obtain an image like the one below. (Note that I've transposed the matrix just because I think it fits better onto the web page.)

[image]

I don't think this is quite "fractal", since the natural limiting object is a line segment due to the shrinking aspect ratio. I can see how one might "see" a fractal, though.

I also don't think that focusing on prime numbers really makes sense. If anything, focusing on the primes obscures the simplicity of the process. Nonetheless, there's lots of primes so you kind of see a similar pattern, if you do so.

Comment: Hey @MarkMcClure. I don't know if my change in your answer collides with your argument. Please review it.

Answer (score 2):

This part of the image:

[image]

where a black area is partitioned vertically from a white area, occurs every time you carry, so e.g. where $X, Y$ and $Z$ are arbitrary binary words, when you go from $X1111Y_2$ to $(X+1)0000Z_2$.

Since primes have gaps, $Y\to Z$ is a relatively random change and its height represents the ceiling base $2$ of the prime gap.  Whereas, the carry operation almost always exchanges any bit sequence of consecutive ones to zeroes in its entirety.

The fractal you are seeing is the frequency of these vertical bars (the long carries), adjusted from every $2^n$ (its frequency in the natural numbers) to that same frequency divided by the density of primes in the integers.

Comment: I would +1 myself for including a manually-drawn red circle, if I could ;)

Comment: I like your answer, but, tell me if you can. Why if we try to get another group more big of primes between $2^n$ and $2^{n-1}$ the figure repeats? Could we conclude that the prime number function $\pi(x)$ has the same distribution between $2^n$ and $2^{n-1}$?

Comment: @RobertoCarlosJoaquinCastro what is repeating, is the repeated exceeding of numbers which are equivalent to $-1$ mod some power of $2$. This happens at a given frequency in the natural numbers. Drawing only primes condenses this map in proportion to the density of primes.

Comment: Not exactly. At first I was thinking that the ratio was 2. For the first groups, it was 2. But from $2^6$, $2^7$,...$2^20$, the ratio is less than 2. I was thinking in the Bertrand Postulate when I tried at first time, thats the reason od my question.